# animate part of text in html (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate.css, impress.js

The goal is simple ->

Say I got a sentence:

"This is a special day for me ..."

And I want the word "Special" being animated (little bounce).

And here's what I tried (I'm using `impress.js` + `animate.css`).

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>

<body class="impress-not-supported">

<div id="impress">

    <div id="first_slider" class="step slide" data-x="-1000" data-y="-1500">
        <h3 style="display: inline">This is a</h3> <h3 class="xxxxx_bounce" style="display: inline">special</h3> <h3 style="display: inline">day for me</h3>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/impress.js"></script>
<script>
    impress().init();

    $('#first_slider').on('impress:stepenter', function() {
        $(this).find("h3.xxxxx_bounce").addClass('animated bounce');
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the whole sentence to be on the same line so I added the "display: inline" part.

This works fine in chrome but in safari the word "special" WON'T BOUNCE at all.

If I remove the `display: inline` part on the word "special", then it works fine in both chrome and safari.  (but the sentence won't be on the same line anymore)

So it seems like the code:

```
$(this).find("h3.xxxxx_bounce")
```

I couldn't find the `h3` element with additional style (display: inline in this case) in safari ?

Is there any way better to get this done ?

Comment: Have you tried `<h3>This is a <span class="xxxxx_bounce">special</span> day for me </h3>`

Comment: Possible for you to create us a https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try inline-block instead of inline.